# How to use CGAL drawing capabilities without CMake?

Tags: c++, qt5, visual-studio-2019, cgal, vcpkg

I am trying to use `vcpkg` "zero configuration" feature. I have installed CGAL in `vcpkg` also as `Qt5`. I can compile and run `CGAL` example with computation only, but I can't run any draw functions. When I do this, it prints

```
Impossible to draw, CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined.
```

and I don't understand, what it wants. It is not C++ define, because this line

```
#define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER 1
```

is present in my code and doesn't help.

What else can be done?

---

It was the problem with location of `#define`. But once I moved `#define` into the beginning, numerous errors like

```
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "QApplication"
```

started to appear. I found that include directive in CGAL code looks like this

```
#include <QApplication>
```

while in standalone Qt5 example (which is working) it looks like this

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication.h>
```

Why?

Comment: You say the line is present in your code, but is it the first line of the file, before any #include ?

Comment: Probably you don't have qt correctly installed on your system; or you don't use the correct compiler or/and linker options for qt.

Comment: @gdamiand standalone example is working

Comment: Did you use the option [qt5] when you installed cgal with vcpkg ?